# With mult-dimensional input vectors, what are the dimensions of the covariance matrix elements? (Gaussian Process)

Tags: gaussian-process, multivariate-normal-distribution, high-dimensional, bayesian-optimization

I am trying to create a Bayesian Optimisation code with a Gaussian Process. My input data, $\vec{X}_i$ is 8-dimensional, where each dimension corresponds to a feature of my data,

$\vec{X}_i = [\alpha_1, \alpha_2, ..., \alpha_8]$.

I plan to use the RBF kernel function to define the covariance matrix.

Is it correct that the kernel function, $K(\vec{X}_i, \vec{X}_j)$, will yield a scalar value $\Sigma _{ij}$, giving the similarity between $\vec{X}_i$ and $\vec{X}_j$? Or, is $\Sigma _{ij}$ a $8 \times 8$ matrix giving the similarity between each feature in the inputs?

Also, I am mapping the inputs $\vec{X}_i$ to a scalar output (my cost function) $y_i$. Is it correct to think of the resulting conditional probability distribution as a multivariate gaussian distribution of dimension equal to the number of known points + number of measured points? Or, is the conditional distribution of dimension 8 (ie a dimension for each feature in my input vector). I am confused as most examples work with 1D input data, and so the difference between 'points' and the features does not exist.